# How can I restore viewport visibility to multiple objects at once?

Tags: mesh, 3d-view

I started working in a new job as 3D designer and replaced the old one who worked with C4D and now I'm working with Blender. I have to use some of his old work done in C4D to make changes etc and I'm curious about one thing.

He made C4D files with a many individual objects and about 90%(about 100-200 objects) of them are hidden.
When I export it as fbx and import it in Blender. These hidden objects are not only hidden, they also have unchecked "**Show in Viewport**" in **Object menu** in **Visibility** option but they are still visible in Renders... Is there a way to make all of these objects to become visible in viewport either in Blender or C4D? I never used c4d before.

I don't want to check viewport visibility for each one of them individualy, that would take ages.

Comment: You could use a simple script that toggles visibility for all objects in the scene. Would that be OK ?

Comment: After my 7 years in Blender I have never used scripting option in Blender. Is there some tutorial or step by step guide how to make it? Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You normally would use the <kbd>ALT</kbd> + click modifier that lets you edit a property on multiple objects. Unfortunately a hidden object can't be selected, and you can't use the modifier on unselected objects.

You can toggle all your objects' visibility with a simple script.

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    obj.hide_viewport = False # Reset the monitor-icon visibility (viewport)
    obj.hide_render = False # Reset the camera-icon visibility (render)
```

If however you want only the objects in the current scene to be visible :

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    obj.hide_viewport = False # Reset the monitor-icon visibility (viewport)
    obj.hide_render = False # Reset the camera-icon visibility (render)
```

If you want only the objects in a specific collection to be visible :

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.data.collections["Collection"].objects: # Replace with your collection name
    obj.hide_viewport = False # Reset the monitor-icon visibility (viewport)
    obj.hide_render = False # Reset the camera-icon visibility (render)
```

[Click here to learn how you can edit and run a script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11604587)

Comment: Thank you! It really works, you just saved me a many hours of work